# git clone error!! couldn't connect to host while accessing

Tags: git

When I write

```
$ git clone htt://mail1003@localhost:9000/mail1003/board** ,(htt means http)
```

this error occurred!

```
 Initialized empty Git repository in /home1/irteam/board/.git/
Password:
error: couldn't connect to host while accessinghtt://mail1003@localhost:9000/mail1003/board/info/refs** (htt means http)
```

when i command this

```
$ export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 ,**
```

result changed, but still same error occur T.T

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /home1/irteam/board/.git/
Password:
Couldn't find host localhost in the .netrc file; using defaults
About to connect() to localhost port 9000 (#0)
Trying 127.0.0.1... * Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1... * Connection refused
couldn't connect to host
Expire cleared
Closing connection #0
Couldn't find host localhost in the .netrc file; using defaults
About to connect() to localhost port 9000 (#0)
Trying 127.0.0.1... * Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1... * Connection refused
couldn't connect to host
Expire cleared
Closing connection #0
error: couldn't connect to host while accessing htt://mail1003@local:9000/mail1003/board/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed** (htt means http)
```

Anyone who know this error's solution help me plz T.T

Answer (score 0):

The url that you pass to git clone points that you are cloning the repository from your local device, from service running in port 9000.   So, curl tries to connect into that and fails. As you can see in the curl log, there are alot of "Connection refused" errors.

So the issue is that you either have wrong url or you need to start the service or check if its blocked by some means.